# roslaunch syntax highlight for qt creator

Tags: ros, qtcreator, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Did  someone used `roslaunch` syntax highlight in `qt creator` ? How to do it ?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185876/roslaunch-syntax-highlight-for-qt-creator/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-07-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2014-07-10**:
I am not using qt creator but roslaunch is XML

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-10**:
i am using qt creator but its not detecting .launch extension as xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution mentioned here to use Tools->Options->Generic Highlighter path and copying a file didn't work for me, because that path is just empty.
What actually worked was this:

1. Going to Tools->Options->Environment->MIME Types
2. Filter for xml
3. Click on the entry "application/xml
4. in The field "Patterns" append ";*.launch" to the already existing patterns

---

Originally posted by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) with karma: 164 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on 2019-12-13**:
I also couldn't find the xml.xml and this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way to get syntax highlighting is actually pretty simple. Open QtCreator and go to Tools->Options->Generic Highlighter.
Then navigate to whatever directory is listed. Lastly,

```
cp xml.xml launch.xml
```

You may need to sudo that command, depending on where it is installed. After that, you should be good.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-14**:
thanks for reply but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Find out, where your **Syntax Highlight Definition Files** are located by navigating to: *Tools->Options->Text Editor->Generic Highlighter* and note the given paths.
2. Find the syntax file for xml: `xml.xml` in one of the paths noted above.
3. You can either edit this file directly or make a copy and name it `launch.xml` (You might need sudo to do this). Then edit the line that starts with `<language name="XML"`  by adding `*.launch` to the `extensions="...` argument. Mine looks like this now:

`<language name="XML" version="2.03" kateversion="2.4" section="Markup" extensions="*.launch;*.docbook;*.xml;*.rc;*.daml;*.rdf;*.rss;*.xspf;*.xsd;*.svg;*.ui;*.kcfg;*.qrc;*.wsdl" mimetype="text/xml;text/book;text/daml;text/rdf;application/rss+xml;application/xspf+xml;image/svg+xml;application/x-designer;application/xml" casesensitive="1" author="Wilbert Berendsen (wilbert@kde.nl)" license="LGPL">`

---

Originally posted by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) with karma: 123 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chuong Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23343/chuong-nguyen/) on 2015-10-27**:
it works after restart QT, thank you.

**Comment by [Nicky0201](https://answers.ros.org/users/28591/nicky0201/) on 2016-11-21**:
I am not able to edit the file ..... is this common?

**Comment by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) on 2016-11-22**:
Hi @Nicky0201, you probably don't have the necessary rights. As I mentioned in my answer, you can try editing the file, using the `sudo` command in the terminal.

**Comment by [Nicky0201](https://answers.ros.org/users/28591/nicky0201/) on 2016-11-22**:
okay thank you